# HTACCESS Rules ISSUE

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the below rule in my .htaccess to prevent direct access to these file extensions.

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?mydomain\.com.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule \.(txt|pdf|jpg|png|svg)$ - [F]
```

It works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. As for Internet Explorer 11 and Edge it block all these file types even if they are not a direct access. E.g. if a page contains image.png that image will not be displayed.

Note it is the same as [(htaccess) How to prevent a file from DIRECT URL ACCESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717) because the direct access is not working only on IE 11 and Edge but working in other browsers.

Comment: .htaccess is handled on the server, not in the browser. If your issue is browser-specific, it's not an issue with .htaccess.

Comment: That is because IE and Edge are not passing `HTTP_REFERER` to server.

Comment: @Adrian well when I comment the last line the error goes away and displays fine.

Comment: @anubhava so any ideas on the way forward.

Comment: @Martin it is not a duplicate. I said it is not working well in IE 11 and Edge. I can confirm this after commenting the last line.

Comment: Is it IE and Edge showing you a cached version of the image?

Comment: @JoshJ it does not, in the logs it displays 403 errors which I think comes from the last rule.

Comment: What is the exact Edge version?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/520244/referer-is-passed-from-https-to-http-in-some-cases-how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [stated by Anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141757/htaccess-rules-issue?noredirect=1#comment75301717_44141757), this appears to be because some browsers do not by default support providing the `HTTP_REFERER` header value.

Reading up about this issue (list of links below) it seems to be one that has slipped between the cracks of web best practise; the value `HTTP_REFERER` is [insecure and easily forged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880671/3536236) (hence more recent editions of various browsers don't include it).

As well as that, it seems to be the only way of checking (surprise!) the referring page to a call to HTML headers.

**This** is why the `.htaccess` behavior changes based on different browsers.

There are a couple of solutions, that I know of, neither are perfect and one take quite a bit of recoding.

## First Solution

The issue with Edge is that a `HTTP_REFERER` value is not given, so simply allow in your `.htaccess` if this value is empty, using a mod_rewrite `OR` flag:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?mydomain\.com(.*)?$ [NC]

RewriteRule \.(txt|pdf|jpg|png|svg)$ - [F]
```

This adds a check for an empty/null `HTTP_REFERER`, then an `OR` logic gate and then I've summarised your previous two rules into a single rule of **domain plus optional filepath string**.

The plus side to this is that Edge [should] work, but that anything which does not supply a `HTTP_REFERER` value (such as a new browser window) will also be allowed. [Read more about a better variation on this approach here](http://tltech.com/info/referrer-htaccess/).

## Secondary Solution(s)

- a) [Use a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978726/how-to-do-htaccess-redirect-based-on-cookie-value) to inform the `.htaccess` that the site has already been visited and to react accordingly. Give the cookie a small timeframe and you'd have to work out your own way of building the cookie setting system.

**OR**

- b) If you want to be really coy, a cookie reading system built into the images, such as using PHP files to call images, itself  masquerading as a `.jpg` file etc. This will do what you need (disallow direct access) but will be a significant work overhead.

For example if you have a file in your `<img src='/image.jpg?x=47457'>` and this `image.jpg` is infact a PHP file that calls a JPG image referenced by `47457`...

- c) You could even extend this with a `mod_rewrite` that any call to a jpg file can infact be redirected to `imageprocessing.php?input=image.jpg`, where the PHP code can then check there is a valid cookie/session data before loading and outputting the appropriately referenced file...

Anyhow (b) and (c) are easily potentially long and complex but could provide the most maulable results.

## Reading List

- [In what cases will HTTP_REFERER be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty)
- [htaccess Redirect only if the HTTP referrer does NOT equal something](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12184543/3536236)
- [Referer checking with htaccess](http://tltech.com/info/referrer-htaccess/)
- [.htaccess Redirect based on HTTP_REFERER being empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512328/htaccess-redirect-based-on-http-referer-being-empty)
- [How to do htaccess redirect based on cookie value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3978726/3536236)